# Deploying a Node.js(+MongoDB) app with Heroku, always Local Port

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, port, web-deployment

I've searched and tried a lot of things, and I can't get my deployment to work.
My node.js app works locally, but doesn't work when deployed on heroku. The problem is the port I'm using, I believe.

In my app.js,I have:

1) a server+port:

```
var server = require('http').createServer();
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
```

2) The port I want to listen to: (I do think this part is wrong)

```
server.listen(port, function() { 
  console.log("Listening on  " + port);
});

app.listen(port);
// app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);

module.exports = app;
```

3) And some other stuff

```
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

 // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

//app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'))


// var routes = require('./routes/index');
var routes = require('./routes/index')(passport);
var users = require('./routes/users');


// make db accessible to the router
app.use(function(req,res,next){
   req.db = db;
   next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
// app.use('/api', api);



// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   var err = new Error('Not Found');
   err.status = 404;
   next(err);
});

// error handlers

//development error handler
//will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
   app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      res.status(err.status || 500);
      res.render('error', {
         message: err.message,
         error: err
      });
   });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
   res.status(err.status || 500);
   res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
       error: {}
    });
});
```

When I'm on my deployed app, and here you can see it says it will redirect to the place I want (at the bottom left)
[the frozen-fortress.../login/facebook..etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS8EJ.jpg)
however, when i actually click on it, it gives me
[localhost:3000/login/facebook...etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT140.png)

This happens with some of my others links too, but NOT all the links.

What can I do the change the port? I have tried things like app.listen(port) as well.

Thank you in advance! (Also I apologize if the format of my question looks funky, this is my first time on stackoverflow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong, but

look at this part of code:

```
var server = require('http').createServer();
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
// ...
server.listen(port, function() { 
  console.log("Listening on  " + port);
});

app.listen(port);
```

You create two servers here: `server` and Express' `app`. Both will try to listen on the same port and one of them will fail. I mean, Express already has `http` server inside, you don't need another one:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app = express()
app.listen(port)
app.use(...)
app.get('/', function(...){
   // there you go
})
```

[Here's doc](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.get) about `listen()` and other Express things

Comment: Thank you! I only needed one of them.